# Check if int is 10, 100, 1000,

Tags: c#, numbers

I have a part in my application which needs to do do something (=> add padding 0 in front of other numbers) when a specified number gets an additional digit, meaning it gets 10, 100, 1000 or so on...

At the moment I use the following logic for that:

```
public static bool IsNewDigit(this int number)
{
    var numberString = number.ToString();
    return numberString.StartsWith("1")
        && numberString.Substring(1).All(c => c == '0');
}
```

The I can do:

```
if (number.IsNewDigit()) { /* add padding 0 to other numbers */ }
```

This seems like a "hack" to me using the string conversion.
*Is there something something better (maybe even "built-in") to do this?*

**UPDATE:**
One example where I need this:
I have an item with the following (simplified) structure:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string HierarchicPosition { get; set; }
}
```

`HierarchicPosition` is the own position (with the padding) and the parents `HierarchicPositon`. E.g. an item, which is the 3rd child of 12 from an item at position 2 has `2.03` as its `HierarchicPosition`. This can as well be something more complicated like `011.7.003.2.02`.
This value is then used for sorting the items very easily in a "tree-view" like structure.

Now I have an `IQueryable<Item>` and want to add one item as the last child of another item. To avoid needing to recreate all `HierarchicalPosition` I would like to detect (with the logic in question) if the new position adds a new digit:

```
Item newItem = GetNewItem();
IQueryable<Item> items = db.Items;
var maxPosition = items.Where(i => i.ParentId == newItem.ParentId)
                       .Max(i => i.Position);
newItem.Position = maxPosition + 1;
if (newItem.Position.IsNewDigit())
    UpdateAllPositions(items.Where(i => i.ParentId == newItem.ParentId));
else
    newItem.HierarchicPosition = GetHierarchicPosition(newItem);
```

**UPDATE #2:**
I query this position string from the DB like:

```
var items = db.Items.Where(...)
              .OrderBy(i => i.HierarchicPosition)
              .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(pageSize);
```

Because of this I can not use an `IComperator` (or something else wich sorts "via code").
This will return items with `HierarchicPosition` like (`pageSize = 10`):

> 03.04
>   03.05
>   04
>   04.01
>   04.01.01
>   04.01.02
>   04.02
>   04.02.01
>   04.03
>   05

**UPDATE #3:**
I like the alternative solution with the `double` values, but I have some "more complicated cases" like the following I am not shure I can solve with that:
I am building (on part of many) an image gallery, which has `Categories` and `Images`. There a category can have a parent and multiple children and each image belongs to a category (I called them `Holder` and `Asstes` in my logic - so each image has a holder and each category can have multiple assets). These images are sorted first be the categories position and then by its own position. This I do by combining the `HierarchicPosition` like `HolderHierarchicPosition#ItemHierarchicPosition`. So in a category which has `02.04` as its position and 120 images the 3rd image would get `02.04#003`.
I have even some cases with "three levels" (or maybe more in the future) like `03.1#02#04`.
Can I adapt the "double solution" to suport such scenarios?

*P.S.: I am also open to other solution for my base problem.*

Comment: I didn't understand your question. can you provide some sample input and desired outputs? :)

Comment: Do you have access to the 'previous' number?

Comment: How about using [`Math.Log10` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.log10(v=vs.110).aspx)? You can check the result is `int` or not for example.. It fails for only `1` based your example.

Comment: `return number.ToString().Length > (number - 1).ToString().Length;`

Comment: if it is `int` you also can use `return n == 10 || n == 100 || n == 1000 || n == 10000 || n == 100000 || n == 1000000 || n == 10000000 || n == 100000000 || n == 1000000000;`

Comment: Can't you first take the highest number from the input to determine the desired length?

Comment: If you are only doing padding why don't you use one of the number formatting functions, `ToString("D4")`?;

Comment: I added one of my usages as an example.

Comment: @NedStoyanov: I actually use that to add the padding, but to avoid position strings like `000000000001.0000000000003.000000000001` I only add as much as actually needed. This would get even worse with `long`...

Comment: Could you provide some sample inputs and outputs of the IsNewDigit function to better understand exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: @SujaySarma: Please see my updated question - this is the code I am using this in...

Comment: @chrfin Is the *HierarchicOrder* in the Database always correct? Does it reflect, when it needs to be "00x" instead of just "0x"?
Do you need a logic to *build* those numbers, or do you just need to sort a readout depending on such values?

Comment: @dognose: The DB always contains the correct format for the `HierarchicOrder`. At the moment I update this value for all items with the same parent if an item is added, which is not needed, as it only changes if "a digit needs to be added" and that is what I want to detect. But yes, the "end goal" is to sort a query after this value.

Comment: @chrfin Updated my post with a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if base-10 logarithm of the number is an integer. (10 -> 1, 100 -> 2, 1000 -> 3, ...)

This could also simplify your algorithm a bit in general. Instead of adding one 0 of padding every time you find something bigger, simply keep track of the maximum number you see, then take `length = floor(log10(number))+1` and make sure everything is padded to `length`. This part does not suffer from the floating point arithmetic issues like the comparison to integer does.

Comment: pretty fragile. Doing `F(x) == 1.0` is unreliable.

Comment: True, but it's true/consistent within known range - just test it up to MAX_INT before - it does match.

Answer (score 1):

From What you describe, it looks like your `HierarchicPosition` position should maintain an order of items and you run into the problem, that when you have the ids `1..9` and add a `10`, you'll get the order `1,10,2,3,4,5,6...` somewhere and therefore want to pad-left to `01,02,03...,10` -  correct?

If I'm right, please have a look at this first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Because what you try to do is a workarround to solve the problem in a *certain* way. - But there might be more efficent ways to actually *really* solve it. (therefore you should have better asked about your actual problem rather than the solution you try to implement)

See here for a solution, using a custom IComparator to sort strings (that are actually numbers) in a native way: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11016/Numeric-String-Sort-in-C

---

Update regarding your update:

With providing a sorting "String" like you do, you could insert a element "somewhere" without having ALL subsequent items reindexed, as it would be for a integer value. (This seems to be the purpose)

Instead of building up a complex "String", you could use a Double-Value to achieve the very same result real quick:

If you insert an item somewhere between 2 existing items, all you have to do is : `this.sortingValue = (prior.sortingValue + next.sortingValue) / 2` and handle the case when you are inserting at the end of the list.

Let's assume you add Elements in the following order:

```
1 First Element // pick a double value for sorting - 100.00 for example. -> 100.00
2 Next Element // this is the list end - lets just add another 100.00 -> 200.00
1.1 Child // this should go "in between": (100+200)/2 = 150.00
1.2 Another // between 1.1 and 2 : (150+200)/2 = 175
```

When you now simple sort depending on that double field, the order would be:

```
100.00 -> 1
150.00 -> 1.1
175.00 -> 1.2
200.00 -> 2
```

Wanna Add `1.1.1`? Great: `positon = (150.00 + 175.00)/2;`;

you could simple multiply all by 10, whenever your NEW value hits `x.5`* to ensure you are not running out of decimal places (but you dont have to - having `.5 .25 .125 ...` does not hurt the sorting):

So, after adding the `1.1.1` which would be `162,5`, multiply all by 10:

```
1000.00 -> 1
1500.00 -> 1.1
1625.00 -> 1.1.1
1750.00 -> 1.2
2000.00 -> 2
```

So, whenever you move an item arround, you only need to recalculate the position of `n` by looking at `n-1` and `n+1`

Depending on the expected childs per entry, you could start with "1000.00", "10.000" or whatever matches best.

---

What I didn't take into account: When you want to move "2" to the top, you would need to recalculate all childs of "2" to have a value somewhere between the sorting value of "2" and the now "next" item... Could serve some headache :)

---

The solution with "double" values has some limitations, but will work for smaller sets of groups. However you are talking about "Groups, subgroups, and pictures with counts of 100" - so another solution would be preferable:

- First, you should refactor your database: Currently you are trying to "squeeze" a Tree into a list (datatables are basically lists)
- To really reflect the complex layout of a tree with an infinite depth, you should use 2 tables and implement the `composite pattern`.
- Then you can use a recursive approach to get a category, its subcategory, [...] and finally the elements of that category.
- With that, you only need to provide a position of each leaf within it's current node.
- Rearanging leafs will not affect any leaf of another node or any node.
- Rearanging nodes will not affect any subnode or leaf of that node.

Comment: `you'll get the order 1,10,2,3,4,5,6... somewhere and therefore want to pad-left to 01,02,03...,10 - correct?` Yes, thats the base problem. I will look at your suggested links...

Comment: I can't use custom `IComperator` as I do that sorting (and paging) "in the DB" - I will add that to the question.

Comment: @chrfin why not change the "HierarchicPosition" to a integer value? They can be sorted native without any effort.

Comment: Because I can not have "multiple levels" (see example in the question) in "one integer".

Comment: THIS is nice - I need to check this with my "most complicated use case" (see update #3 to the question)...

Comment: Do you have any examples for the `composite pattern` using trees in DBs (or with Entity Framework). I am still searching on my own, but so far I only found "code solutions" (which are using classes, which I can not in SQL)...

Answer (score 1):

You could check sum of square of all digits for the input, 10,100,1000 has something in common that, if you do the sum of square of all digits, it should converge to one;

10
1^2 + 0^2 = 1
100
1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1

so on so forth.